# Nodemailer on Node.js powered static site

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer, harp

I am rather desperate of a simple problem. I run a static site on Harp, Node powered static site server. On Harp’s docs there is a method of including externally served forms (via Woofoo). This could be simple (actually, I am not successful with that) but I think it is not elegant.

I have tried Nodemailer and it works like a charm when I am calling it from the CLI. However, I am not able to call it’s functions from inside the site > logically > browser is not able to call or use the node typical *require* function.

I am convinced there should be a simple hack how to do this. Any advice more than welcome!

I wish I was able to use it for a simple contact form.

Comment: If your question, is how to use node mailer from inside the browser, then no, you can't do that. You need to connect to a server.

Comment: browserify can do the "require trick"  with some node modules. But front-end javascript does not support mailing so i think that it does not work.

Comment: Understand, thank you! I was just wondering why not to use Node in the case when it is used by Harp itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reiterate what some of the commenters pointed out, Nodemailer is a server-side Node.js module, which means it can’t run client-side using Harp or anything else.

That constraint for static sites has resulted in few services trying to fill this gap. We wrote the Wufoo integration as one option, since it’s entirely client-side (if there seemed to be something wrong with that page, feel free to [open an issue on our docs](https://github.com/harp/harpjs.com) and we’ll look into it).

Another good alternative I have been using more recently is [Formspree](http://formspree.io/), which is specifically for static sites. It might be closer to what you’re looking for, since it doesn’t require JS or an iframe.

Thoughtbot also builds a similar one called FormKeep, but it is only free while you are developing.

Comment: Thank you! Formspree looks quite good! It would be the right solution here… I will check the Wufoo solution again. The only one thing I realized it didn’t show up in the page (the interface for embedding code has slightly changed but the code is identical, I thinik).
(The point was I was wondering why I couldn’t use Node with Nodemailer > Harp runs on Node, doesn’t it? :) )

Comment: Harp is built with Node, but its final output is static HTML, CSS, and JavaScript you can run on any server, inside a Cordova/PhoneGap app, whatever. So Harp can’t take advantage of server-side Node modules since it isn’t actually going to be executing that code on the server: it is just providing the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

That said, It’s possible you might be able to wire this up with Express, using Harp and Nodemailer [as Express Middleware](http://harpjs.com/docs/environment/lib), but this introduces a lot more complexity you probably won’t need just for a contact form.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Finally, I have solved that just a few minutes before the answer mentioning Formspree > with Express. I will definitely use Formspree later, now the issue is solved and I am happy. Thanks! :)